# How make SQL Developer to display all lines in the Edit View window with 600+ SQL lines?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a view with 695 lines (the view was made in PL/SQL Developer by another person). 
The problem is that SQL Developer (version 17.2) in Edit View window displays only the first 355 lines of code.
SQL Developer in the SQL tab  displays all lines properly - and the view is working fine.

However, when I right click on view -> Edit  it shows only first 355 lines - therefore making the code fail the Check Syntax or Test. I can't modify the code from the Edit View or use this view as template.

So the only option to modify the view is by using CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW in the worksheet or by coping the whole code from SQL tab to the worksheet, making the edit and then pasting it into Edit View (after paste all lines are visible in Edit View, but after I close the Edit View and open it - again it displays only first 355 lines)

Is there any way to always display all lines in the Edit View window?

Answer (score 3):

A little late on the matter, but in my case "Ctrl + End" did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There's none, as far as I know. You can set number of fetched rows in Tools - Preferences - Database - Advanced - SQL Array Fetch Size which can be set to any value between 50 and 200. So - 200 is the maximum.

However, once you get result data set, press "Ctrl + Page Down" which will *force* SQL Developer to reach the end.